# Unable to generate PDF using hyperref along with babel[arabic]

Tags: hyperref, arabic, dvips

I am unable to generate PDF when using `hyperref` & `bookmark` package alongwith `\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}`. If I remove the packages `hyperref` & `bookmark`, then PDF generated successfully.

Please find the MWE in below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}\AR{صفر}\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}\AR{الحمد لله رب كل العالمين.}\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}\AR{الرحيم الرحيم.}\end{otherlanguage}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \subfloat[][a]{\includegraphics{figure1}\label{figure1}}
     \subfloat[][b]{\includegraphics{figure2}\label{figure2}}
     \caption{Comparison of steady state results (a) x method (b) y method}
     \label{steady_state}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

After DVI->PS, we are getting the below error during distilling:

```
%%[ Error: limitcheck; OffendingCommand: cvn ]%%

Stack:

(subfigure.\\protect \\protect \\bgroup \\beginL \\protect \\protect \\edef OT1{OT1}\\let \\enc@update \\relax \\protect \\xdef \\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 {\\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 }\\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 \\size@update \\enc@update \\def OT1{O...)
/Dest
[/XYZ 86.0023 440.288 -null-]
/View
-mark-

%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

Please do the needful.

Comment: Does it work with pdftex?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Yes. I am facing this issue with dvips.